# Merging different sized data frames and plotting the difference of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

i have two dataframes Region_education_0 and Region_education_1
`Region_education_0`

| index | Region | ConvertedComp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Australia/New Zealand | 122573.834171 |
| 2 | Caribbean | 53562.111111 |
| 3 | Central Asia | 134422.000000 |
| 4 | East Asia | 112492.507042 |
| 5 | Melanesia | 605 |

`Region_education_1`

| index | Region | ConvertedComp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Australia/New Zealand | 122573.834171 |
| 2 | Caribbean | 53562.111111 |
| 3 | Central Asia | 134422.000000 |
| 4 | East Asia | 112492.507042 |

Index 5,  Melanesia  is not present in Region_education_1 because of a condition, i want to compare them and plot so i tried this

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

Region_education_combined=Region_education_0.merge(Region_education_1,left_on="Region",right_on="Region")
Region_education_combined.columns=["Region","Max of Bachelors Higher Ed","Higher Formal Education"]
Region_education_combined['Diff_HigherEd_Vals'] = Region_education_combined['Higher Formal Education'] - Region_education_combined['Max of Bachelors Higher Ed']
print(Region_education_combined)
comp_df.style.bar(subset=['Diff_HigherEd_Vals'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

| index | Max of Bachelors Higher Ed | Higher Formal Education | Diff_HigherEd_Vals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 151698.500659 | 122573.834171 | -29124.666488 |
| 2 | 28413.753425 | 53562.111111 | 53562.111111 |
| 3 | 3944.750000 | 5883.000000 | 1938.250000 |
| 4 | 45091.041667 | 27052.384615 | -18038.657051 |

Region column is missing from the output,to include I region tried

```
comp_df.style.bar(subset=['Diff_HigherEd_Vals','Region'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

and

```
comp_df.style.bar(Region_education_combined, align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

Is there any way to include region in the final output?
and i left out "Index 5,  Melanesia" from 'Region_education_0' dataframe is there any way to include that too in the output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain the missing Region by using `how="outer"` when you call `merge` like this

```
Region_education_combined=Region_education_0.merge(Region_education_1,left_on="Region",right_on="Region")
```

Pay attention that in this case you will have a table which contains `Nan` where it is not possible to merge, in your case `Melanesia` will have a `Nan` in the `Higher Formal Education` column. In order to avoid problem you can set a default value with this

```
Region_education_combined["Higher Formal Education"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: working like a charm thanks <3